# Jenkins after HTTPS reverse proxy keeps on redirecting to HTTP

Tags: jenkins

We have set up Jenkins behind an Apache reverse server with HTTPS. Although the default Jenkins URL is set to https://... in Jenkins and links on the GUI are working fine, all redirects ("302 Found") are pointing to HTTP, e.g. here:
[image: browser]
I could not find any existing thread on this here. Is there maybe some setting we might still be missing?

Addendum: This is the reverse proxy configuration we are using:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Portable/laragon/etc/ssl/abc-pub.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Portable/laragon/etc/ssl/abc.pem"

<Directory "C:/Portable/laragon/www/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/running+jenkins+behind+apache
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins

ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# Local reverse proxy authorization override
# Most unix distribution deny proxy by default (ie /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf in Ubuntu)
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: As usual: share all text content **in text form**

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks, I have added the Apache reverse proxy configuration (in text form :-) and asked the moderators to move to serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following statements to the Apache reverse proxy virtual host configuration:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

This does not solve the Jenkins issue but works around by rewriting HTTP requests as HTTPS.

Comment: Configure the proper URL in Jenkins. See https://serverfault.com/questions/931485/jenkins-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-in-subdirectory/931486#931486

Comment: I wonder how can I set it up for an AWS ALB

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System` ->  `Jenkins Location - Jenkins URL` to the actual url of your jenkins.